# nexus 7 onboard keyboard issues

Tags: keyboard, ubuntu-touch, nexus-7, onboard

when i start up ubuntu on my nexus 7, i am greeted with the first time setup screen. However, I cannot type into text fields using the onscreen keyboard. The keyboard does not seem to be outputting anything; none of the mouse click emulations nor text enrty are working. I can click on buttons and the keyboard is responding to taps (animations/options screens ect.) but is not giving any output into other windows. i got it working once but it stopped working right before i could confirm my password...

Answer (score 0):

Just reboot your device by keeping the power button pressed. After this reboot it will work.